# How can I do AMDGPU-PRO Overclock on CentOS / Linux ..?

Tags: graphic

I'm Looking for how to overclock RX470 / RX580 AMD grahpic card on CentOS7 or Ubuntu..

I just successed to modify fan attribute but, I couldn't do memory / core clock / voltage..

And I don't know how to show AMD graphic cards state on CentOs

RX series doesn't meet aticonfig config command so i don't what to do ..

these graphics are working on well , But I don't know what can i do to overclock these graphic cards...

I installed amdgpu-pro 17.30 driver on Centos7 and It works well..

Is there anybody who knows overclock AMDGPU-PRO RX* graphic card??

Plz Help me..

Thank you for reading !

Comment: This is the wrong site to ask this question. Try: https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Look if you can find /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_force_performance_level

and then you echo "high" > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_force_performance_level

that should set the coreclock to highest setting.

To further increase coreclock und vram clock you can do that in

/sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_sclk_od

=> GPU clock seems to be a sort of multiplier CAUTION!!!

/sys/class/drm/card0/device/pp_mclk_od

=> MEM clock seems to be multiplier CAUTION!!!!

hope that helps you